# Community bulletin eventually overlaps questions count details (Firefox 57)

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

When I browse tagged questions, sometimes pages look normally, and sometimes they have this visual bug:

[image]

When I try examining the HTML, the bug immediately disappears.

Comment: `When I try examining HTML, bug immediately disappears.`. FF is FF Quantum. I think that explains everything.

Comment: I'd report this to the Firefox dev team. You're using beta software, the bug isn't StackOverflow's fault (can't replicate in FF 56, the latest release version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented - we do not support software in alpha/beta state, precisely because of issues like this.

Once FF 57 is stable, if this is indeed an issue that is on our end (and not, say, a regression in the FF rendering engine), we will fix it.